# Rewrite rule for dynamic slashes

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've dynamic category names for pages. I just need last digit for get correct category IDs.

For example;

http://example.com/category/cat1/cat2/cat3/123

http://example.com/category/cat1/cat2/cat3/cat4/cat5/456

http://example.com/category is static

here is my rule; regex works fine on tester, but page gives 500 error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule \d+(?=\D*$) index.php?CID=$1 [L]
```

Comment: An http status 500 ist a generic status that only indicates an issue inside the server side logic. It does not name any specific issue, since that would be a security issue, you certainly do _not_ want everyone out there to know what issue your server has. You instead want to know about the exact issue, that is why you need to take a look into the error log file your http server writes. That is where you can _read_ what the specific issue is instead of having to guess.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the regex pattern you are using inside that second RewriteRule. Maybe you can elaborate what the idea is here? And what you expect ``$1`` to contain if it matches? I would instead suggest a simple pattern like `/?category/.*/(\d+)$` based on what I undestand from your question ...